# gdb - no reference to source code when debugging library built with clang

Tags: gdb, clang, clang++

I use Ubuntu 20.04 and gdb 9.2 to debug an application. A backtrace for the library which has been built with clang 15 (with option `-fno-limit-debug-info`) doesn't contain a reference to the source code - only the information "from libName.so". Moreover I get the following info:

```
Dwarf Error: DW_FORM_strx1 found in non-DWO CU [in module libName.so].
```

Is it possible to fix that ?

Comment: Can you update GDB?  That warning was removed in gdb 10.1 and replaced with some actual code, so it might just work.